# UnicodeDecodeError, changes randomly

Tags: python, file

I have a bunch of Pandas DF that I saved to multiple .csv files. Before I was able to run a loop and read them all without and problems, but now when I get to the third file I get a decode error. I've even remade all the dataframes and saved them the exact same way but am still getting an error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

The error happens after I try to read the file.

```
    for file in os.listdir('path'):
        file = open('path'+file, 'r')
        team = file.read()
```

When I create the dataframes I'm getting a bunch of info in a couple dictionaries, converting to df and exporting it to .csv

```
    champSalaryData = pd.DataFrame(easy_dict)
    
    #Write dataframe to csv file
    champSalaryData.to_csv('Champ_Salaries/' + champ + '-' + year +'.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Saved *how*? Definitely not as UTF8, otherwise no byte would have the value `0x80. The problem is the saving code, not reading. Python 3 strings are UTF-8 and reading uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: None of the visible characters in that screenshot is above `0x7F` so the screenshot isn't helpful. Images in general aren't helpful. What if there's an invisible character there? A non-breaking space? An accented character in the next line?

Comment: I wrote them as a dataframe in Pandas and saved them as a .csv file, I have 20 .csv's the first two work perfectly but once I get to the third that's where I get the problem

Comment: Post your code. `0x80` will never appear in UTF8. It doesn't matter how many files there are, they aren't UTF8. Does the data contain the Euro symbol? Did you same the files as Latin1 or Windows-1252? The Euro symbol isn't part of the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding

Comment: What  does the file that causes the problem contain? What's at position 3131?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this is pretty much all I'm doing, there's a bunch of functions that scrape data before, I put that into dictionaries, convert to df, then export to .csv

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, about 5 columns and 13 rows of information, nothing blank, either a name or a number

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if it would look at a file called .DS_Store, this is why it could never read the file. I'm not sure why this would happen but I've solved it, thanks anyways.